# How manually add customUI to excel file?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

As far as I know it should be enough to add customUI/customUI.xml file and modify _rels/.rels file.
Couple yeas ago I succesfully made file like that, but with newly created xlsm Excel file it fails.

i've tried:
add to .rels file:

```
<Relationship Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="/customUI/customUI14.xml" Id="R131e66a518624244" />
```

with customUI14.xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <officeMenu>
            <button id="MyCustomButton1" label="My Macro" imageMso="HappyFace" onAction="Macro1" />
        </officeMenu>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

and I tried add to .rels file:

```
<Relationship Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="/customUI/customUI.xml" Id="R131e66a518624244" />
```

with customUI.xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <officeMenu>
            <button id="MyCustomButton1" label="My Macro" imageMso="HappyFace" onAction="Macro1" />
        </officeMenu>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

in both scenarios Excel says that the file is corrupted. Any ideas?

Edit:
Probably I packed folder instead files inside folder...

Answer (score 1):

Yeash... so the problem was that I manually was packing whole folder instead its content only